# C++ : const reference to local object

Tags: c++

```
const std::string s1 = "abc";
const std::string & s2 = "abc";
```

Is the definition of `s2` legal? If so, what is the difference between between `s1` and `s2`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, s2 is legal. s2 is bound to a temporary std::string - extending the temporaries lifetime. s1 isn't a temporary, it's a named variable.

See 12.2/5:

> The second context is when a reference
>   is bound to a temporary. The temporary
>   to which the reference is bound or the
>   temporary that is the complete object
>   to a subobject of which the temporary
>   is bound persists for the lifetime of
>   the reference except as specified
>   below.

Comment: So what guarantees are there about the lifetime of the temporary to which s2 refers in this case? (i.e what are the exceptions)

Comment: @B Tyler: Lifetime is the lifetime of the const ref. The exceptions are half a page in the (C++03) standard, in general the above works unless you're binding to something that's temporary in another scope than the binding one.

Answer (score 3):

Both are legal.
S1 is a variable of the type std::String with a const Qualifier.
S2 is const Reference to a temporary of the type std::string.